# How to explain the process of deriving a mathematical expression-Number 2?

Tags: sentence-construction

suppose that we have derived two expression  as below.

a = b+c  (1)

y = w-z  (2)

Now, suppose we've been asked to solve an integral. to explain how to solve the integral, I say:

1. > The integral can be solved from (1) and (2) under simple modifications. To do so, we only need to ...
2. > The integral can be solved using (1) and (2) under simple modifications. To do so, we only need to ...
3. > The integral can be solved by/via/through (1) and (2) under simple modifications. To do so, we only need to ...

Questions:

1) Which one do you prefer?

2) If there is a better option, I will be happy to know it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't seen the last choice used, but the first ones.
The first two are commonly used.

Another way I'd add is: *by using* (1) *and* (2), *the integral can be solved ...*